# Importing file from parent directory, only modifying code in parent file

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-import

I'm writing an API for a CLI tool which will allow users to add plugins to a folder in the main directory. The current structure looks like this:

```
project
|___api.py
|   ...
|___plugins
    |___plugin1.py
    |___plugin2.py
```

What I want to accomplish is for users to only need to write `import api` in their plugin file (which will be in a subfolder, importing from the parent directory). The following don't seem to work:

```
import project.api
import api
from project import api
```

I've read about dynamically importing files from different directories using `importlib` [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html?highlight=importlib#importing-a-source-file-directly), but this code goes in the file that is *doing* the importing and I don't want users to have to do this. A similar case is used with plugins for the Sublime Text editor; plugins are placed in the `Packages` directory and they have access to `import sublime_plugin`, yet, when run on their own, the script will raise `ModuleNotFoundError`. After a bit of searching, I discovered the plugins are executed a different directory (in the directory where `sublime_plugin` is), but couldn't find how this occurs. Is there a way to replicate this behaviour?

The being executed is `plugin1.py`. The working directory when running it is:

```
C:\Users\...\project\plugins
```

Comment: Can you try like this? ```from project import api``` and also it matters from where you are importing.

Comment: The same `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project'` is raised. I am importing `api` from `plugin1.py`, to clarify.

Comment: Can you print from where you are running? ```import os``` and next line ```print(os.getcwd())```

Comment: CWD is `C:\Users\...\project\plugins` - the `plugins` directory in the project structure above.

Comment: Guess we have no other option than this one ```import ..api```

Comment: I don’t think Python allows relative imports except in the form `from .. import x`.

Comment: You can check it out here. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/